# I want to animate a transition onClick to push the old data away and slide the new data in when I change the props of a component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, css-animations

I want to animate something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eICRp.gif)
when the user clicks the next button or back button to navigate through a list of projects in my React app.
But I'm not pushing a new component in place of another one, I'm just changing the props on the same ProjectCard component that is rendered.

Is it possible to animate this if I'm only changing the props?

```
export default function Projects(props) {
    const {projects} = props; 
    const [project, setProject] = useState(projects[0]);
    const { id, title, platform, description, tools, startDate, endDate } = project; 


    {/* The projects are stored in a list passed down from the parent. onClick, I just   navigate to the previous or next item in the list. */}
    const getPreviousProject = () => {
       setProject(projects[id - 1])
    }
    const getNextProject = () => {
        setProject(projects[id + 1])
        // setProject(projects[id + 1])
    }

    return (
    
            <div className="Projects">
                <h1 className='Projects-header'>Projects</h1>
                <Paper style={{backgroundColor:'transparent'}} elevation={10}>
                   
                    {/* This is the component I want to animate when props change */}
                    <ProjectCard 
                        id={id}
                        title={title}
                        platform={platform}
                        startDate={startDate}
                        endDate={endDate}
                        tools={tools}
                        description={description}
                        key={id} 
                    />
                    
                      <IconButton 
                        className='button-prev'
                        style={{ color:'white'}}
                        onClick={getPreviousProject}
                        disabled={id <= 0}
                    >
                        <ArrowBackIos />
                    </IconButton>
                     <IconButton 
                        className='button-next'
                        style={{ color: 'white'}}
                        onClick={getNextProject}
                        disabled={id === projects.length - 1}
                        
                    >
                        <ArrowForwardIos />
                    </IconButton>
                </Paper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Right now, it just switches the props with no animation. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FQgx.png)

Comment: It would be possible to animate by only changing the props but the I would think that the implementation would be much easier to have all the `ProjectCard`s available per `project` and manipulating the position instead.